# Is it possible to integrate html with asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net

We are working on a website project. Most of the pages on the website are HTML based. There is an order form that is designed using ASP.NET.

Since I am new to ASP.NET, I wish to know if it is possible to integrate the HTML and ASP together in a single website. For example, if I click on a tabbed menu option in the HTML page, I want the ASP to open preferably following the same layout of the existing HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its simple. ASP.Net just uses html. Any links css etc. should work with with both.
Think of ASP.NET being an extension of HTML for ease of creating a dynamic website.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is a server side language for generating HTML. So yes, this is possible.

Before you start on this project it would be worth learning the basics. There's loads of free tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NEt only uses HTMl to Load the Content in WebBrowser. So you should able to integrate with Asp.Net. Also I think you are talking about the Same Layout for new Aspx. in Asp.net we Uses **MasterPage, ContentPlaceHolder**.